# How do you get a THREE.Line to render in the right order?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a model solar system and I am using THREE.Line to make my orbits. They look fine until you go in front of a planet and you realize that they are all being rendered behind the Meshes. I've tried playing around with render order and depthwrite but they just make it so that the line is either entirely in front of or entirely behind the planet. I feel like this should be an extremely easy thing to do.
The effect, if you'd even consider it an effect is like this:
[what i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG25h.jpg), you can see one orbit that fully wraps around that planet.
this is what my problem looks like:[what i have[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZquYo.jpg).

Here is the function that makes my orbits:

```
function MakeOrbit_2(base, color) {
    function semiminor(a, e) {
        return a * Math.sqrt(1 - (e * e));
    }
    var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
        foci(1000 * base[9], semiminor(1000 * base[9], base[0])), 0,            // where the middle is
        1000 * base[9], semiminor(1000 * base[9], base[0]),           // xRadius, yRadius
        0, 2 * Math.PI,  // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
        false,            // aClockwise
        0                 // aRotation
    );
    var material = color;
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(curve.getPoints(points))
    var orbit = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    orbit.rotateX(- Math.PI / 2);
    orbit.rotateZ(DegToRad(base[3]));//ascn
    orbit.rotateX(DegToRad(base[2]));//inc
    orbit.rotateZ(Math.PI + DegToRad(base[4]));//aop
    scene.add(orbit);
    return orbit;
}
```

I have   `renderer.sortObjects = false;` so my transparent atmospheres and clouds render properly.
It is also worth noting that my less opaque lines behave differently than the fully opaque ones.
Update: turns out this weird effect was due to rounding errors, the scale was on billions of units and the difference in position were too minuscule to bother the z-buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working example by [Sander Blue](http://sanderblue.github.io/solar-system-threejs) along with his [GitHub source code](https://github.com/sanderblue/solar-system-threejs).  I was unaware of 3D Javascript until I saw this post, amazing!  Also your name... my mom's family name is Logan and my dad's is Brotherston... how about that?  I don't have a direct answer to your question but I hope that these links help.  It appears to be a working example of just what you were asking about... showing orbits in front of a planet as you rotate the view.